# "_" is not convertible to Int32 - Swift

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, int32

Getting this error and don't understand why.

This line below works. Note that both settingVersion and settingRelease are Strings:

```
let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: [settingRecord.settingVersion, settingRecord.settingRelease)
```

But if I add an Int32 into the mix, where settingsTimesUsed is an Int32, I get the "_" is not convertible to Int32 error.

```
let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: [settingRecord.settingVersion, settingRecord.settingRelease, settingRecord.settingTimesUsed])
```

I also get the same error if I make the final item completely explicit as an Int32, e.g.

```
let a = 1 as Int32
let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: [settingRecord.settingVersion, settingRecord.settingRelease, a])
```

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an `Int32` tries to move this from `[String]` to `[AnyObject]`. Swift will never automatically infer `Any` or `AnyObject`. You must make that explicit if you need it. In this case, that would be:

```
let settings: [AnyObject] = [settingRecord.settingVersion, settingRecord.settingRelease, settingRecord.settingTimesUsed]
let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: settings)
```

That said, I'd make sure you really want that. This throws away type safety in running `executeUpdate`.

If this is an ObjC interface (which are commonly type-unsafe), then it probably actually takes an `NSArray`. In that case, you can just be explicit by calling:

```
...withArgumentsInArray: NSArray(objects: settingRecord.settingVersion, settingRecord.settingRelease, settingRecord.settingTimesUsed))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the type safety of the other variables, instead of casting the entire array to 'AnyObject', you could just cast that particular variable to a string to get around this issue.

For example

```
let settingTimesUsedString = String(settingRecord.settingTimesUsed)

let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: [settingRecord.settingVersion, settingRecord.settingRelease, settingTimesUsedString])
```